# QT Creator executable file variable

Tags: qt-creator

I am looking for an environment variable in QT Creator that contains the path and name to the executable file located in the project build directory. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `%{CurrentProject:Name}` variable. Though it does not contain the path but only executable file name. For path you can use `%{buildDir}` variable.

So in general it looks like this: `%{buildDir}/%{CurrentProject:Name}`